# Is there any method to search particular texts in a certain app?

Tags: search

I need to search some certain texts in a certain app. These texts are real-time and server-sided so they only appear when I am using that app and tap (+) button.

Have any third-party app(s)/non-programming method(s) [for searching] come into your mind?

Comment: No, at least not if the function isn't built into the application. I don't know how a 3rd party app could search in another app's data, especially when all the data is held server-side.